# Is there an equivalent of CLR Memory Diagnostic (CLRMD) for Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, profiling, heap-memory, clrmd

The title is quite explicit: is there an equivalent of CLRMD for Mono, or at least any way to non-invasively read the heap of an external Mono process in order to get the list of all allocated objects and read their fields ?

If there is no such tool, is there an API and a documentation about the structure of the heap of a Mono process that would allow me to implement my own strategy for this purpose ?

Comment: If there are mono profilers, there should be something.